# RSocket Channel with Spring Boot - Clients miss their own first message

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor, rsocket

Suppose I have a simple RSocket and Spring Boot Server. The server broadcasts all incoming client messages to all connected clients (including the sender). Client and server look like this:

Server:

```java
  public RSocketController() {
    this.processor = DirectProcessor.<String>create().serialize();
    this.sink = this.processor.sink();
  }

  @MessageMapping("channel")
  Flux<String> channel(final Flux<String> messages) {
    this.registerProducer(messages);
    // breakpoint here
    return processor
        .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> logger.info("sub"))
        .doOnNext(message -> logger.info("[Sent] " + message));
  }

  private Disposable registerProducer(Flux<String> flux) {
    return flux
        .doOnNext(message -> logger.info("[Received] " + message))
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        // .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .subscribe(this.sink::next);
  }
```

Client:

```java
  @ShellMethod("Connect to the server")
  public void connect(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rsocketRequester = rsocketRequesterBuilder
        .rsocketStrategies(rsocketStrategies)
        .connectTcp("localhost", 7000)
        .block();
  }

  @ShellMethod("Establish a channel")
  public void channel() {
    this.rsocketRequester
        .route("channel")
        .data(this.fluxProcessor.doOnNext(message -> logger.info("[Sent] {}", message)))
        .retrieveFlux(String.class)
        .subscribe(message -> logger.info("[Received] {}", message));
  }

  @ShellMethod("Send a lower case message")
  public void send(String message) {
    this.fluxSink.next(message.toLowerCase());
  }
```

The problem is: the first message a client sends is processed by the server, but does not reach the sender again. All subsequent messages are delivered without any problems. All other clients already connected will receive all messages.

What I noticed so far while debugging

- when I call channel() in the client, retrieveFlux() and subscribe() are called. But on the server the breakpoint is not triggered in the corresponding method.
- Only when the client sends the first message with send() is the breakpoint triggered on the server.
- Using the .delayElements() on the server seems to "solve" the problem.

What am i doing wrong here?
And why does it need the send() first to trigger the servers breakpoint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A `DirectProcessor` does not have a buffer. If it does not have a subscriber, the message is dropped.

(Citing from its [Javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/DirectProcessor.html): *If there are no Subscribers, upstream items are dropped*)

I think that when `RSocketController.registerProducer()` calls `flux.[...].subscribe()` it immediately starts processing the incoming messages from `flux` and passing them to the sink of the processor, but subscription to the processor has not happened yet. Thus the messages are dropped.

I guess that subscription to the processor is done by the framework, after returning from `RSocketController.channel(...)` method. -- I think that you are able to set a breakpoint in your `processor.doOnSubscribe(..)` method to see where it actually happens.

Thus maybe moving a `registerProducer()` call into a `processor.doOnSubscribe()` callback will solve your issue, like this:

```
  @MessageMapping("channel")
  Flux<String> channel(final Flux<String> messages) {
    return processor
        .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> this.registerProducer(messages))
        .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> logger.info("sub"))
        .doOnNext(message -> logger.info("[Sent] " + message));
  }
```

But I think that personally I would prefer to replace a `DirectProcessor` with `UnicastProcessor.create().onBackpressureBuffer().publish()`. So that broadcasting to multiple subscribers is moved into a separate operation, so that there could be a buffer between the sink and subscribers, and late subscribers and backpressure could be handled in a better way.